# how remove specific data in laravel casts as array

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

I have retrieved data from my database as an array like this

```json
{
    "1":"5",
    "2":"7",
    "3":"4",
    "4":"7"
}
```

for example, I want to delete `["2":"7"]`. how to do it in Laravel?

Answer (score 1):

If you correctly set the `$casts` property you can access it as an array right out of the box, or use arrow array key notation:

https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-mutators#array-and-json-casting

```php
$model = YourModel::find(1);
unset($model->arrayColumn["2"]);
$model->save();
```